# Trying to dump a PostgreSQL-10 DB running in a CentOS 7 machine and restore it into a Windows 10 machine

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-10

I am trying to execute a backup of my PostgreSQL-10 database running on a CentOS 7 machine and then to restore it in a development machine running Windows 10, but I am getting errors during the restore process:

```
pg_restore: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
```

I have made sure that the commands' parameters passed in both dump and restore are the same:

```
pg_dump --format=c --compress=9 --encoding=UTF-8 -n public --verbose --username=postgres databaseName -W -f /usr/local/production-dump.backup
```

However it does not work at all. Even though the schema is restored, the data is not, because right before the restore process is going to start restoring data, it gives a "pipe has ended" error and does not proceed with the full restore process. I am using the "custom" format because the plain SQL or tar formats generate huge backup files.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any parameter that I need to pass to the dump or restore commands?

Comment: What's the size of the backup file? Are you sure it was transferred in binary mode to the windows machine (no LF->CRLF conversion)? And what's the origin of the pg_restore binary on the windows host? An installer (which one and which exact version)?

Comment: @DanielVérité the size of the backup file is about 200MB. It was created in centOS using command line and then transferred to the windows host using WinSCP tool. On windows I used the command: `pg_restore.exe --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --format=c --dbname=myDatabaseName`. On both centOS and windows, the pg_dump and restore binaries are from postgresql-10

Comment: 200MB is small enough that it can't be a 32-bit overflow problem. But for winscp, please make sure that you explicitly select the binary transfer mode otherwise it can corrupt your file. See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode#scp

Comment: I enabled the binary transfer and got the same results

Answer (score 0):

The likely explanation is that the file was modified during file transfer. Could you calculate a checksum of the file before and after transfer and verify that it is the same?

If the file did not change, then you have probably found a PostgreSQL bug. If you have a dump that you can share and that exhibits the problem, please report this problem to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Interestingly, the pg_restore worked when I used pgAdmin to run the restore process. I was using DBeaver enterprise to execute pg_restore, and, in theory, it should execute de same command. tks

Comment: Interesting. Does DBeaver have its own copy of `pg_restore`? If yes, you could try to call that `pg_restore` directly to see if you can reproduce the problem. Then DBeaver must have a buggy version. If DBeaver doesn't have its own `pg_restore`, then it would be interesting to know which `pg_restore` it called and how. `strace` may help to answer such questions.

Comment: Maybe DBeaver has its own copy of pg_restore, thanks for noticing that